# How to get high performance under a large transaction (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, transactions

I have data with amount of 2 millions needed to insert into postgresql. But it has played an low performance. Can I achieve a high-performance inserter by split the large transaction into smaller ones (Actually, I don't want to do this)? or, there is any other wise solutions?

Comment: Without knowing the root cause of your problem, it's very hard to solve the problem. Lucky shot: Did you try COPY to insert the data?

Comment: What do you mean by "low performance"? A correctly working postgres on pretty usual SSD hardware should be able to insert around 50k-200k rows per second unless you have some code running on triggers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the main idea to have it much faster is doing all inserts in one transaction. Multiple transactions, or using no transaction, is much slower.

And try to use copy, which is even faster: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-copy.html

If you really have to use inserts, you can also try dropping all indexes on this table, and creating them after loading the data.

This can be interesting as well: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/populate.html

Comment: Thank you very much, do you know the reason why all in one transaction   run faster than multiple-smaller ones ? I am thirsty for the theory. :)

Comment: " If you allow each insertion to be committed separately, PostgreSQL is doing a lot of work for each row that is added."  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/populate.html

Comment: Performance for a large number of INSERT can also be improved by inserting several rows with a single insert (or e.g. using batched statements in JDBC)

Comment: Thank you, but What I mean is not to allot transactions to each insertion. for example, there are 2-million records needed to insert, I will insert 10000 records in one transaction, so it will open 20 transactions than one. would it get a higher performance?

Answer (score 5):

Possible methods to improve performance:

1. Use the `COPY` command.
2. Try to decrease the `isolation level` for the transaction if your data can deal with the consequences.
3. Tweak the PostgreSQL server configuration. The default memory limits are *very low* and will cause disk trashing even with a server having gigabytes of free memory.
4. Turn off disk barriers (e.g. `nobarrier` flag for the `ext4` file system) and/or `fsync` on the PostgreSQL server. **Warning:** this is usually unsafe but will improve your performance a lot.
5. Drop all the indexes in your table before inserting the data. Some indexes require pretty much work to keep up to date while rows are added. PostgreSQL may be able to create indexes faster in the end instead of continuously updating the indexes in paraller with the insertion process. Unfortunately, there's no simple way to "save" current indexes and later restore/create the same indexes again.

Splitting the insert job into series of smaller transaction will help only if you have to retry the transaction because of data dependency issues with paraller transactions. If the transaction succeeds on the first try, splitting it into several smaller transactions run in sequence will only decrease your performance.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience you CAN improve INSERT time-to-completion by splitting a large transaction into smaller ones, but only if the table you are inserting to has NO indexes or constraints applied, and NO default field values that would have to contend for a shared resource under multiple concurrent transactions.  In that case, splitting the insert into several distinct parts and submitting each concurrently as separate processes will complete the job in significantly less time.